# Pivot by occurrence number in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have data like the following:

[image]

I want to pivot the data to look like this. There are a maximum of three oPack values per Size, and I'd like all the oPack values for each combination of Category + Category2 + Size to be listed in increasing order in the last 3 columns.

```
Category   | Category2 | Size      | Pack1 | Pack2 | Pack3
Chilled...  Chilled     1.75-1.89L  1750    1890    NULL
Chilled...  Chilled     1.75/1.89L  1750    1890    NULL
Chilled...  Chilled     1.75L       1750    NULL    NULL
Chilled...  Chilled     1.89/2.63L  1890    2630    NULL
...
Chilled...  Chilled     400-710mL   400     NULL    NULL
```

I tried something like :

```
select [Category],[Category2], [Pack1], [Pack2], [Pack3]
from (
  select [Category],[Category2],[size], oPack
  from myTable) p
pivot (Max(oPack) for oPack in ([Pack1], [Pack2], [Pack3])) as pvt
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, in a PIVOT you are implicitly grouping by some attribute(s), what attribute(s) are you grouping by? From your example data and results I can't tell

Comment: Please provide better sample data & results and describe better what you are trying to do

Comment: Not sure how I can make it any more obvious - for each group of rows which have the same category, category2 & size values, I want to pivot so that the unique oPack values get put into 3 separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives exactly what you're looking for. First, a little table preparation.

```
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Drinks') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Drinks;
GO
CREATE TABLE #Drinks (
   Category1 varchar(40),
   Category2 varchar(40),
   Size varchar(20),
   Pack int
);

INSERT #Drinks VALUES
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.75-1.89L', 1750),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.75-1.89L', 1890),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.75/1.89L', 1750),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.75/1.89L', 1890),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.75', 1750),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.89/2.63L', 1890),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.89/2.63L', 2630),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1.89L', 1890),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1L', 1000),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '1L', 1000),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '2.63L', 2630),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '2.84L', 2840),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '250mL', 250),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '3.78L', 3780),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '355mL', 355),
   ('Chilled Juices & Drinks', 'Chilled', '400-710mL', 400),
   ('Frozen Juices', 'Frozen', '1.60L', 1600),
   ('Frozen Juices', 'Frozen', '1.40L', 1400);
```

Then, your solution:

```
WITH Nums AS (
   SELECT
      *,
      'Pack' + Convert(varchar(30), Dense_Rank() OVER (
         PARTITION BY Category1, Category2, Size ORDER BY Pack)
       ) PackNum
   FROM #Drinks
)
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Nums
   PIVOT (Max(Pack) FOR PackNum IN (Pack1, Pack2, Pack3)) P;
```

And, an alternate solution that could be useful:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   #Drinks
   PIVOT (Max(Pack) FOR Pack IN (
      [250], [355], [400], [1000], [1400], [1600],
      [1750], [1890], [2630], [2840], [3780]
   )) P;
```

Comment: Thank you both for your continued effort.Hi ErikE, your solution looks like it's close, however the different packs are on their own separate rows, ie. the 3 different packs for category+category2+size should be on the same row.

Comment: @Perplexed Could you give an example? I can't find 3 packs for the same category+category2+size that my query doesn't put on the same row... Would you add more sample data or more sample output rows to clarify the difference?

Comment: oK, using your sample table it works great - however not with my table. Does having a primary key column affect the pivot? Ah ha! It does - :) Thanks very much it works!

Comment: @Perplexed With PIVOT, you often have to put only the desired columns in a derived table or CTE, since it implicitly groups by all the nonpivoted columns. `SELECT * FROM #Drinks PIVOT ...` becomes `SELECT * FROM (SELECT OnlyDesiredColumns FROM #Drinks) D PIVOT ...`. Is this the problem you were having?